# How to run an ".exe" file from "C:\Program Files (x86)" using python?

Tags: python

***Context:*** Basically I want to create a python program that asks me what Software I want to run, as soon as I start my computer.

***Usefull code:*** `os.chdir(r'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe')`. And that's the error I got :

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 os.chdir(r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'")

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'"

The translation for "Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden:" is the system was unable to find the file.

***Problem:*** My problem is that I can't run any ".exe", or any type of files, because of the white spaces in *"C:\Program Files (x86) "*, so my question would be how can I bypass that? / What could I use to make it work?

PS: I searched, on various forums, but this problem doesn't seem to be very common... Or I didn't search enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.system()` or give a folder path to change dir in `os.chdir()` not an executable file (why would you want to change into an executable? You can't do that)

Comment: ok thanks for the quick answer. I'm going to try this, I fund the `os.chdir()` on the internet, and quickly checked what it did, actually it opened files, so I thought that's what I need :,)

Comment: It does not open files, some other code did. It changes working dir only.